# iAds Doesn't Load Ads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

**iAds Doesn't Load The Ads
The AdsBanner is only white with my App When I publish it to the appstore
This Is the code for the iAds That i put**

this is the first method block

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    //banner is invisible row and moved out of the screen on 50 px
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
     self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

}

}
```

---

this is the second method block

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    //banner is invisible row and moved out of the screen on 50 px
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

}

}
```

---

this is the third method block

```
-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:   (BOOL)willLeave{

NSLog(@"Banner view is beginning an ad action");
BOOL shouldExecuteAction = YES;
if (!willLeave && shouldExecuteAction) {

    [UIImageView commitAnimations];

}
return shouldExecuteAction;

}

-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{

[UIImageView areAnimationsEnabled];

}
```

Comment: Did you set up your application for iAds in iTunes Connect?

Comment: My app is having same thing. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ui-maker-design-mobile-app/id791072042?mt=8 . I have applied the Delegate methods of iAds to show when First Ad is loaded, until then I am keeping iAds Hidden. I have re-verified again on iTunes connect.. Still no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click your app in iTunes Connect in the "Manage your applications" section and click "Set up iAd network"

[image]

Comment: then i have already set it up it came for 1 time and didn't came for 100

Comment: My app is having same thing. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ui-maker-design-mobile-app/id791072042?mt=8 . I have applied the Delegate methods of iAds to show when First Ad is loaded, until then I am keeping iAds Hidden. I have re-verified again on iTunes connect.. Still no success...